# rails unit test notifications on windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using rails on windows. I want unit tests to watch file changes and to run automatically in the background. Can anyone direct me to a link that explains how to do that?

I could not find something that works. I know growl can help here but I could not make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked into watchr https://github.com/mynyml/watchr

Comment: thanks for the link, I got it to run my tests all the time. I am still looking for growl-like functionality. tried to integrate growlnotify with watchr but could not find how to do so.